# Windows Phone: NavigateToAction sometimes reinitializes view, sometimes not

Tags: c#, xaml, view, windows-phone

I've tried to solve the following problem for several hours now:
I'm developing a game, where I have to switch between several views. When I'm in the game view, at the end there is a button called "Return match" which navigates back to the "PlayerSelectView" where the players are set up:

```
<Button Tag="{Binding Source={StaticResource Options}, Path=Effect}" Width="300" MinHeight="70">
            <localControls:DropShadowTextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedText.GV_ReturnMatch}"/>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ic:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Result, ElementName=MessageBoxBehavior}" Value="OK">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding NewGameCommand}" />
                    <ic:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="/Views/PlayerSelectView.xaml" />
                </ic:DataTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:MessageBoxBehavior x:Name="MessageBoxBehavior" Text="{Binding LocalizedText.MAIN_YouWillLoseYourPreviousGame}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsGameInitialized}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>
```

The NewGameCommand doesn't reset the players list in the PlayerSelectViewModel.
At this time the constructor of PlayerSelectView and the constructor in the PlayerSelectViewModel is not called, so it preserves the state, as it should be, but, going back to the menu during the game with this code:

```
    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        GameViewModel.Instance.GameIsPaused = true;

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/MainPageView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

and after that going back to the GameView with the Continue button:

```
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding IsGameInitialized, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" Tag="{Binding Source={StaticResource Options}, Path=Effect}" Width="300" MinHeight="70" FontWeight="Normal">
            <localControls:DropShadowTextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedText.MAIN_Continue}"/>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                    <ic:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="/Views/GameView.xaml" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

When I now hit "Return Match", the PlayerSelectView always gets reinitialized!

Why does it now reinitialize the PlayerSelectView? The other thing is, that when the new players are set up again and the game is started, it just returns to the Game Over screen (which is a popup layer on the GameView).

Does anyone have an idea what to do?

UPDATE:
When the game starts, the MainView is shown. From there the user is taken to the PlayerSelectView with this button:

```
       <Button Tag="{Binding Source={StaticResource Options}, Path=Effect}" Width="300" MinHeight="70">
            <localControls:DropShadowTextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedText.MAIN_NewGame}"/>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ic:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Result, ElementName=MessageBoxBehavior}" Value="OK">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding NewGameCommand}" />
                    <ic:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="/Views/PlayerSelectView.xaml" />
                </ic:DataTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:MessageBoxBehavior x:Name="MessageBoxBehavior" Text="{Binding LocalizedText.MAIN_YouWillLoseYourPreviousGame}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsGameInitialized}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>
```

Here players are created and edited. The game starts with this button:

```
<Button Command="{Binding StartGameCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding NavigationService, ElementName=PlayerSelectViewControl}"  Tag="{Binding Source={StaticResource Options}, Path=Effect}" Padding="0">
            <localControls:DropShadowTextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedText.PLSEL_StartGame}"/>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                    <ic:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="/Views/GameView.xaml"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

...which runs this code as well:

```
private void StartGame()
    {
        BusinessLogic.GameLogic.Initialize(new List<Player>(Players));
    }
```

From there, the user can go back to the MainView (menu), exit the game (the state is preserved) or change options.

Comment: can you detail how the pages are related regarding forward/back navigation?

Comment: I've updated the post with some information. Do you need more?